# How to pass an argument to the EventHandler

Tags: c#

No it's not that kind of basic question. I am doing a application and got a scenerio like, the file will be downloaded then it will be uploaded to the FTP server, then the local copy will be deleted, then one entry will be placed in a dictionary for that filename. So, the code is below

```
public void download_This_WebPage(string url, string cookies_String, string local_Saving_File_Name_With_Path)
{
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();
    wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookies_String);
    // Below I want to pass this local_File _Path to the event handler
    wb.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wb,);
    wb.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), local_Saving_File_Name_With_Path + ".html");
}

public void data_Download_Completed(Object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
{
      //use the file name to upload the file to FTP

}

public FTP_Completed
{
    // Delete the file
}
```

But, I dont know how to pass that filename to the event handler of download_Completed. Can anybody guide me in this

**EDIT:**
   Thank you for the answers from "Darin" and "Frederic". Is there any general way to pass the custom data to the (already defined)event handler like below

```
void main_Fn()
{
    string my_Data = "Data";
    some_object a = new some_object();
    some_Object.click_event += new eventHandler(click_Happened);
    (Assume that the event passes two ints, I also want to pass the string "my_Data"
      to "click_Happened")
    some_object.start();
}

void click_Happened(int a, int b)
{
   // I want to get the string "my_Data" here. 
}
```

In short how to trick the signature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the file name in the `userToken` argument to [DownloadFileAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144197.aspx). When the operation finishes, it will be available in the `UserState` property of the [AsyncCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.aspx) argument passed to `data_Download_Completed()`:

```
string filename = local_Saving_File_Name_With_Path + ".html";
wb.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), filename, filename);
```

Then:

```
public void data_Download_Completed(Object sender,
    System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    string filename = (string) args.UserState;
    // Now do something with 'filename'...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, is there anyway to inject user defined data into the eventhandler?.

Comment: @prabhakaran, well, you can pass any type in `userToken`, including an instance of any `class` or `struct`, and it will be available in `UserState`.

Comment: Forgive my grammar mistake. I meant how to do this to any event handler?

Comment: @prabhakaran, no, there is no way to "trick the signature". If the handler delegate takes two `int` arguments, you have to provide two `int` arguments, no more, no less. You can try associating `my_Data` with `some_Object` another way, like with e.g. a static map associated with the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 3-rd argument of the `DownloadFileAsync` method which allows you to pass an `UserState` to the completed handler:

```
// subscribe to the completed event
wb.DownloadFileCompleted += data_Download_Completed;
string file = local_Saving_File_Name_With_Path + ".html";
wb.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("url"), file, file);
```

and inside the handler:

```
public void data_Download_Completed(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    // extract the filename from the UserState of the args
    string file = args.UserState as string;
    ...

}
```

Comment: I dont know who made the answer first. Thanks to you for the solution. Same question to you. Is there any way to inject the user defined data into the event handler.

Comment: Yes, there is, using the UserState property as illustrated in my answer. You could pass an arbitrary complex object instead of a simple string.

Comment: Forgive my grammar mistake. I meant how to do this to any event handler?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Is it OK , that if I give put the tick on Frederic's answer. Because his score is much less than yours.